# How to replace regex to pattern from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string: 
http://zrack-profile-a.comaihd.net/foobar.jpg which I want to convert to 
http://z-r.ac.zrack.net/profile.ac/foobar.jpg

So first I check whether the string input matches a regex:

```
regex = "^(https?)://(?!z-[mn])(zrack)([0-9a-zA-Z.-]+)(-a.comaihd).net(:?[0-9]{0,5})"
```

The code: `input.match(regex)` returns `true`. and so now I need to replace this regex with another pattern.

```
pattern = "$1://z-r.ac.zrack.net$5/$3.ac$6"
```

Then I do `inputNew = input.replace(regex, pattern)`. However this does not change inputNew at all; inputNew == input. What am I doing wrong? Also the input string can be a variety of things, and that is why my regex is more complicated that needed for the above input string provided.

The following works perfectly in PHP.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
input = input.replace(regex, pattern);
```

`String#replace(...)` only performs the replacement and returns a **new** `String` instance; it does not modify the original string.

**EDIT**

Perhaps it might have to do with how you've defined your regular expression? It needs to be a literal that is bounded by `/` and not by `"`:

```
regex = /^(https?):\/\/(?!z-[mn])(zrack)([0-9a-zA-Z.-]+)(-a.comaihd).net(:?[0-9]{0,5})/;
```

You can also use the `RegExp` object:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^(https?)://(?!z-[mn])(zrack)([0-9a-zA-Z.-]+)(-a.comaihd).net(:?[0-9]{0,5})");
```

Comment: Yes sorry inputNew = input.replace(regex, pattern); does not work. inputNew === input

Comment: Your regex literal is incorrect.  You need to escape the forward slashes in the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

`regex` needs to be a regular expression literal

```
regex = /^(https?):\/\/(?!z-[mn])(zrack)([0-9a-zA-Z.-]+)(-a.comaihd).net(:?[0-9]{0,5})/
```

or you need to create a new `RegExp` object

```
inputNew = input.replace(new RegExp(regex), pattern);
```

You may want to make it case insensitive.

Also, your posted regex returns `http://z-r.ac.zrack.net/-profile.ac$6/foobar.jpg`, not `http://z-r.ac.zrack.net/profile.ac/foobar.jpg`.

**Edit**: Fixing typo.